# Emacs tabs not working

Tags: python, emacs, tabs

I'm using Emacs to write a Python script, and for some reason when I try to open tabs past a certain amount it doesn't let me do it.  Does anyone know how to fix this so I can open as many tabs as I want?

In other words, is there anything in the Emacs config file that sets limits on how many tabs you can put?

Comment: `tab-stop-list` could *potentially* limit this (it certainly will in some modes); but I wouldn't expect it to be relevant for a programming mode. Give more detail, anyway. You don't even tell us what "a certain amount" means, or how python mode is configured. A recipe to reproduce the issue would be the most useful thing.

Comment: This question displays some difficulty with python-mode resp. Emacs options. However it's a useful one, also developers might reflect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Control-q TAB</kbd> should insert a literally TAB-character